# What does it mean if robots.txt allows everything and disallows everything?

Tags: python, mechanize, robots.txt

I am trying to scrape several websites using beautiful soup and mechanize libraries in python. However, I came across a website with the following robots.txt

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /
```

According to wikipedia, Allow directive counteracts the following Disallow directive. I have read about simpler examples, and understand how it works, but this situation is a bit confusing for me. ***Am I right to assume that my crawler is allowed to access everything on this website?***
If yes, it seems really strange that the website would even bother writing robots.txt in the first place...

**Extra information:**
Mechanize gave me an error when I tried to scrape this website, and the error was something along the lines of `Http error 403, crawling is prohibited because of robots.txt`. If my assumption stated above is correct, then I think the reason mechanize returned an error while trying to access the website is because it is either not equipped to handle such robots.txt or it follows a different standard of interpreting robots.txt files. (In which case I will just have to make my crawler ignore robots.txt)

**Update:**

I just stumbled upon this question

[robots.txt allow root only, disallow everything else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226432/robots-txt-allow-root-only-disallow-everything-else?rq=1)

in particular, I looked at the @eywu's answer, and now I think my initial assumption was wrong, and I am only allowed to access website.com but not website.com/other-stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update is correct. You can access `http://example.com/`, but not `http://example.com/page.htm`.

This is taken from [Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt), look at the very bottom of the page in the section titled "Order of precedence for group-member records" which states:

```
URL allow:  disallow:   Verdict Comments
http://example.com/page /p  /   allow    
http://example.com/folder/page  /folder/    /folder allow    
http://example.com/page.htm /page   /*.htm  undefined    
http://example.com/ /$  /   allow    
http://example.com/page.htm /$  /   disallow
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't believe I didn't read Robots.txt specification first :D

Comment: No problem, 2 sets of eyes better than one.

Answer (score 0):

No, your crawler can only access the homepage.

The `Allow` directive lets you access `/$`; the `$` is significant here! It means only the literal `/` path matches, any other path (like `/foo/bar`) is not allowed as per the `Disallow` directive, which matches all paths (it has no `$`).

See the [Google documentation on path matching](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#url-matching-based-on-path-values):

> 2. `$` designates the end of the URL

Mechanize correctly interpreted the `robots.txt` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!